# multiple objects with same name

Tags: java, oop

With the code below, three objects with the same name are created. How can I call upon one of them to print out its values?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class ProcessPurchases {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        Purchase aPurchase;

        for (int count = 0; count < 3; count++){
            aPurchase = new Purchase();
            aPurchase.amount = myScanner.nextDouble();
            aPurchase.quantity = myScanner.nextInt();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) Print out the value in the loop or, 2) Save the objects in a List/ArrayList which be accessed later .. note that objects don't "have names" in that sense. It's just that the given variable (for a limited time) can *refer* to the different objects, but only one at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you're making 3 instances of the Purchase class, but you're only storing a reference to one of them at a time since you're overwriting the reference three times.  You probably want something like this

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class ProcessPurchasses {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        Purchase[] aPurchase = new Purchase[3];

        for (int count = 0; count < 3; count++){
            aPurchase[count] = new Purchase();
            aPurchase[count].amount = myScanner.nextDouble();
            aPurchase[count].quantity = myScanner.nextInt();
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can do something like
aPurchase[0].amount to get the amount for the first purchase instance, etc.

Comment: What happens to the previous instances -- are they just deleted or are they rewritten? Also, once the second instance is created, are the amount and quantity values still the same until new ones are input, or are the values default as specified in the Purchase class?

Comment: @user3476493 They are not overwritten with your new values, and each new instance is completely independent of the others. Since no more references to the previous instances exist, they become eligible for garbage collection and eventually will be destroyed by the JVM.

Comment: When you overwrite the reference, there is no longer anything pointing to that instance.  Since there is no longer any way to access the object, the JVM's garbage collector will automatically free up the memory.

Comment: When you create the second instance, the amount/quantity values don't change for the first instance, but on the new instance, they will be initialized to zero (or whatever the Purchase constructor sets them to).  But in your code, since you were overwriting the reference, then you would not have access to the first instance anymore, and thus also would not have access to the amount/quantity of the first instance either since those are instance variables.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between the field of an object and the object itself, in the following snippet :

```
    for (int count = 0; count < 3; count++){
        aPurchase = new Purchase();
        aPurchase.amount = myScanner.nextDouble();
        aPurchase.quantity = myScanner.nextInt();
    }
```

you initialize the object every time, but you should notice that `amount` and `quantity` are fields (variables that belong to the class) that get assigned too.

So if you investigate the code carefully you'll see that there is something like this around :

```
    class Purchase{
        //these are called the fields of the class
        double amount;
        int quantity;
        ....
    }
```

To get a better understanding, at the start of your journey in the OOP, assume an object as (the realization of) an entity, like **Box** and the fields as it's properties, like **width**,**height**,**color** and etc.